# Sort array of objects alphabetically first, and then by numbers

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, kotlin

I have an array of objects (`Drinks`) that contains a `theDrinkName` field. I would like to be able to sort the `Drink` objects `theDrinkName` field alphabetically first, and then numerically.

Here's the function that I use to generate all drinks.

```
data class Drink(val theDrinkName:String)

object DrinkData {

    fun generateAllDrinks():Array<Drink> {
        return arrayOf(
            Drink("Vodka"),
            Drink("rum"),
            Drink("Gin"),
            Drink("151"),
            Drink("99")
        )
    }
    
}
```

And I sort it alphabetically (based on `theDrinkName`) with the following:

```
val allDrinks = DrinkData.generateAllDrinks().sortedBy { it.theDrinkName.toLowerCase().first()}.toTypedArray()

for (drink in allDrinks){
    println(drink.theDrinkName)
}
```

This prints the following:

```
151
99
Gin
rum
Vodka
```

**By default it sorts numbers first, and then by letters. How do I sort this data by letters first, and then numbers, as seen below:**

**Desired result:**

```
Gin
rum
Vodka
151
99
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort first by the indication whether the fist char is a digit and then by the full name:

```kotlin
val allDrinks = DrinkData.generateAllDrinks().sortedWith(
    compareBy<Drink> { it.theDrinkName.first().isDigit() }
        .thenBy { it.theDrinkName.lowercase() }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:
The reason you are getting numbers before the words is because alphabets have larger ASCII value than digits. You can add a space before words to lower their comparison value and use that for sorting.

```kotlin
DrinkData.generateAllDrinks().sortedBy { drink ->
    drink.theDrinkName.lowercase().let { if (it[0].isDigit()) it else " $it" }
}
```

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/aLJlF1rXP)